# insertar y acualizar en la misma tabla en codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

soy nuevo en Codeigniter, estoy creando un Ws en php que me inserte datos en la base de datos y luego que los actualize dependiendo el id de usuario y device y si no que me mande un message que corresponda a datos insertados, datos actualizados y que si existe un token repetido que no me deje insertar hasta ingresar un nuevo token.

este es el código en el controlador:

```
 public function token(){
    $idToken = $this->input->post('id_token');
    $tokenDevice = $this->input->post('token');
    $device = $this->input->post('device');
    $Os = $this->input->post('so');
    $idUsuario = $this->input->post('id_usuario');
    $date = $this->input->post('date');

    $arrayToken = array('id_token' => $idToken,
                        'token' => $tokenDevice,
                        'device' => $device,
                        'so' => $Os,
                        'id_usuario' => $idUsuario,
                        'date' => $date);
    $data = $this->Api_model->token($arrayToken);
    $this->output->set_status_header(200);
    $apiResponse['message'] = $data['message'];
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode( $apiResponse, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

y este es el codigo del modelo:

```
public function token($data){
   $this->db->where('token', $data['token']);
   $this->db->where('id_usuario', $data['id_usuario']);
   $query= $this->db->get('tbtoken');
   if($query->num_rows() == 0) {
        if($query->num_rows() >= 0) {
            $object = array('token' => $data['token'],
                    'id_usuario' => $data['id_usuario'],
                    'device' => $data['device'],
                    'so' => $data['so']);
            $this->db->insert('tbtoken', $object);
            $data['message'] = "token guardado con exito";
            return $data;
        }else{
            $this->db->where('id_usuario', $data['id_usuario']);
            $object = array('token' => $data['token'],
                    'id_usuario' => $data['id_usuario'],
                    'device' => $data['device'],
                    'so' => $data['so']);
            $this->db->update('tbtoken', $object);
            $data['message'] = "token actualizado con exito";
            return $data;
        }
    }else{
        $data['message'] = "token repetido";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

creo que el problema esta en el modelo pero no se muy bien como resolverlo cualquier ayuda estaría perfecto saludos.

Comment: porque validas dos veces la misma query a cero??? es decir si la primer validación da 1 o mas el token esta repetido, pero debajo vuelves a validar y si da 1 o mas realizas la inserción? no se supone es lo que intentas evitar con la primer validación? No tiene sentido lo que hiciste alli

Comment: @carlosQuintero lo que pretendo hacer con esa validacion es ver si es un nuevo token que lo inserte que si el id_usuario existe actualize en el mismo id_usuario.

Comment: en esta linea `if($query->num_rows() >= 0) {`es donde veo el problema,  en la linea en cuestión indicas lo opuesto es decir que si es igual a cero o mayor inserte el registro, ahora cuando se cumple el **else** de esa clausula si la validación es igual o mayor a cero???? nunca va a realizar un update

Comment: gracias @CarlosQuintero ya funciono el detalle era las consultas que estaba haciendo Saludos!!